# Multiple VBA Macros In 1 Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first ever post so please excuse any naivety.

I'm working on a spreadsheet in Excel but I'm very new to VBA and need a lot of assistance with this part.

There are 4 tabs where data will be input and often the quality is poor and needs tidying up before it is used elsewhere for mail merges and similar.

The tabs are named "Goodwill", "Refund", "Furniture Goodwill" and "Furniture Refund"

The working area runs from cells A1 to V500. Row 1 contains headings and needs to remain untouched.

Once the raw data has been input to each tab I am needing to have a macro that will do the following for each tab in turn:-

1. The data in column A will be the inputting people's names. I need to delete any rows that contain data in column A but are then blank in all other columns up to column V.
2. I then need to delete any rows that are empty and then move all the data up so I have a block of information.

3.The remaining data then needs to be trimmed to remove any preceding and trailing spaces plus any random ones in the middle.

4. The data then needs to be formatted in to Proper text so that it is ready for mail merge.
5. The now finished data then needs to be split in to sections of 25 rows and exported in to new tabs to meet the requirements of the mail merge.

Is there code that can do all of these things? If there is, can this contained within 1 macro or does it need to be 1 per function?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: To directly answer your question: yes, there is a code that can do all these wonderful things. However you are asking way too many things at once, and your question is not specific (which is against the guidelines of StackOverflow). So what I suggest to you is that you hit up some tutorials on vba and write this code yourself. There are a lot on the webs. I began at http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html and I think that's a really good site to learn.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I did not mean to be non-specific so apologies for that. I have managed to resolve the "Proper Text" conversion piece so hopefully the others will be referenced in the site you mention. Thank you for giving me direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep every "function" ina separate `Sub`, and have them called one after another from a "main" sub, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim shtNames As Variant, shtName As Variant

    shtNames = Array("Goodwill", "Refund", "Furniture Goodwill", "Furniture Refund")
    For Each shtName In shtNames
        With Worksheets(shtName)
            DeleteRowsWithNoData .Name
            DeleteEmptyRows .Name
            RemoveLeadingAndTrailingSpaces .Name
            SplitToTabs .Name, 25
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub DeleteRowsWithNoData(shtName As String)
    Dim iRow As Long
    With Worksheets(shtName) '<--| reference passed worksheet
        With .Range("V2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:V range from row 2 down to last column A not empty row
            For iRow = .Rows.count To 1 Step -1 '<--| iterate rows backwards up to row 2 to prevent skipping rows
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(iRow)) <= 1 Then .Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
            Next
         End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteEmptyRows(shtName As String)
    With Worksheets(shtName) '<--| reference passed worksheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A from row 1 down to last not empty row
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete '<--| if any blank cells then delete corresponding entire row
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Sub RemoveLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(shtName As String)
    With Worksheets(shtName) '<--| reference passed worksheet
        With .Range("V2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A from row 1 down to last not empty row
            .Value = Evaluate("if(" & .Address & "<>"""",trim(" & .Address & "),"""")")
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub SplitToTabs(shtName As String, nRows As Long)
    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = 1
    With Worksheets(shtName) '<--| reference passed worksheet
        With .Range("V2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:V range from row 2 down to last column A not empty row
            Do
                .Rows(iRow).Resize(nRows).Copy Destination:=GetNewSheet(shtName & "-" & CStr(iRow \ nRows + 1)).Range("A1")
                iRow = iRow + nRows
            Loop While iRow < .Rows.count
         End With
    End With
End Sub

Function GetNewSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    With Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set GetNewSheet = .item(shtName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If GetNewSheet Is Nothing Then
            Set GetNewSheet = .Add(after:=.item(.count))
            GetNewSheet.Name = shtName
        Else
            GetNewSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and where you can insert a similar "function" for the *Proper* issue, which you wrote you already solved yourself

Comment: @BillyH, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi there! Sorry been away for a while. I didn't meant to come across ungrateful or rude. No I couldn't get it to work. I really am a novice and spoon feeding is needed here. I ended up finding singular samples of code to copy/paste in to the macro editor and got most of the tasks in there covered. What I have is not ideal but works to a point. It could be refined though. I would thank you for your input to this. Its really appreciated. :)

Comment: If you're interested in making it work you could write about issues you encountered

Comment: That's a thought... I'll run it again shortly and publish the result. I am a noob at this Stackoverflow thing and at VBA and was grateful for the help but didn't want to put anybody to too much trouble :)

Comment: SO works like that: you post a coding issue and people try helping you giving answers which you are kindly asked to give feedback to until one of them satisfies your need. that's when you mark it as accepted, while you may also up-vote whatever answer you found useful, too

Comment: Thank you for your continued guidance.

Comment: I've run the macro again and had different results to before so I was obviously doing something badly wrong. The macro is working with none of the run errors I was getting before. The conversion to proper text is not working in any way and data remains as before. Just a thought on this, on any proper text macro can column M be excluded as this contains postcodes which need to stay as capital letters? (I omitted to mention this earlier) All other areas work perfectly.

Comment: Well, my code isn't handling the _Proper_ area because you wrote you already had a working macro for this purpose. So since my code works perfectly in all other areas you may want to mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. While if you have other issues than you could make a new post showing your code and efforts and ask for help. thank you

Comment: Apologies, I'd forgotten about that! I do have that so will try to incorporate it. My workaround does work and puts everything in to proper text, I then have a further macro that I run on column M to convert it back to upper. I'm a noob but learning slowly. Thank you so much for your help. It's very much appreciated, I've ticked the box for you :)